# Android / Layout - Build pragmatically main activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm learning how build progmatically the layouts for an app that i need to develop.
I have reproduced the correct layout in the xml file, and now i want do it progmatically (it will become dynamic).
I have some doubts that needs clarifications.
So, here it is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20sp"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".DiLand" >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <RelativeLayout  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/grayColor"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp" > 
       <TextView  
            android:text="1 copy"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:textColor="#000"     
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
            android:padding="25dp"/>
        <TextView  
            android:text="$20"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:textColor="#000"    
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
            android:padding="25dp"/>    
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here there is my java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo_management);

        //SCROLL VIEW
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
        scrollView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        scrollView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        //LINEAR LAYOUT
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //RELATIVE LAYOUT
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor));
        //Need to understand how put a margin top to the relativeLayout

        //TEXT VIEWS
        TextView numberCopies = new TextView(this);
        numberCopies.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        numberCopies.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        numberCopies.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
        numberCopies.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackColor));
        numberCopies.setText("2 copies ");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsNumberCopies = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) numberCopies.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParamsNumberCopies.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        numberCopies.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsNumberCopies);

        TextView priceCopies = new TextView(this);
        priceCopies.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        priceCopies.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        numberCopies.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
        priceCopies.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
        priceCopies.setText("$ 25 ");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsPriceCopies = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) priceCopies.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParamsPriceCopies.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        priceCopies.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsPriceCopies);

        scrollView.addView(scrollView);
        scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
        scrollView.addView(relativeLayout);    
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to launch the activity, the program crash and give me this kind of error:
- ClassCastException Android.widget.linearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

So i need to understand what i'm doing wrong and what can i do for show correctly the layout. It's the first time that i'm trying to do this and i found some tutorials here on stackoverflow that help me to understand better. But probably i'm missing some experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view's layout params must be compatible with its parent view. In your case you have a `View`  inside a `RelativeLayout` but you are supplying it with `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` which gives you the `ClassCastException`.

In your code the `LayoutParams` are unqualified so it boils down to your imports where you probably have

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
```

When dealing with multiple kinds of parent layouts for `LayoutParams`, it's better to just import the layout class

```
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
```

and then in code instead of plain `LayoutParams` use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
```

to qualify it from other `LayoutParams`.

Comment: thanks for explanation. If i remove my "import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;" in the lines like "scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));" it required to me to import it. But i don't understand how can i  modify my code...

Comment: finally i understood. I have fixed my code and now it's working correctly! Thank you very much!